# Discord.py loop song command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was wondering how I could make a command to loop a song and then once the command is ran again, It would stop looping the current song.

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def loop(ctx):
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    current_song = queuee[0]
    song_name = songs[0]
    if loop == '':
        loop = 'True'
        await ctx.send("Looping current song.")
        while True:
            player = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(queuee[0], **ffmpeg_options)
            vc.play(player)
        if loop == 'False':
            break
    if loop == 'True':
        loop = 'False'
    if loop == 'False':
        loop = 'True'
```

I tried doing an external variable but that won't really work

Answer (score 0):

I think you should utilize booleans. That way, when you want to set `loop` to false if it is true and vice versa, you can do `loop = not loop`. You could store `loop` outside of the the command function, so it is saved. Additionally, you can do `while loop:` instead of `while True:`, which will allow you to remove your conditional `break` statement at the end of the loop.

To see if `loop` has a value, you can compare it to `None` by checking `loop is None`, instead of doing `loop == ''`.

Note: A better solution would be to keep a list of channels that are currently being looped on, so you can play music in multiple voice channels at once.

```py
loop = None

@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def loop_command(ctx):
    global loop
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    current_song = queuee[0]
    song_name = songs[0]

    if loop is None:
        loop = True
        await ctx.send("Looping current song.")

        while loop:
            player = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(queuee[0], **ffmpeg_options)
            vc.play(player)

    loop = not loop:
```

Comment: Do you mean `loop = not Loop`? Otherwise you could just write `loop = False`

Comment: Yeah, I meant that. I've fixed this.

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'loop' referenced before assignment

Comment: I've just updated my post. You needed to define `loop` outside of the function, and rename the function to something other than `loop`.